# How to prove that $\frac1a+\frac3b+2(a+\sqrt{b^2+8})>11$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Hello everyone: I want to prove that the following holds for all $a,b>0$: $$\frac1a+\frac3b+2(a+\sqrt{b^2+8})>11.$$

My attempt: We notice by AM-GM that $\frac1a+2a\geq 2\sqrt 2$ for all $a>0$. So we only need to prove that $$\frac3b+2\sqrt{b^2+8}>11-2\sqrt{2}.$$

This seems to be true [numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+3%2Fb%2B2+sqrt%28b%5E2%2B8%29-11%2B2+sqrt%282%29), but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Note that at the boundaries $x\to 0$ and $x\to\infty$, the function in question explodes. In between, we have (by finding the real root of a sixth order polynomial) $$f'(x_0)=0\iff x_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{3 \left(24-\sqrt{573}\right)}+\sqrt[3]{3
   \left(24+\sqrt{573}\right)}}}}.$$ And also we have $$f(x_0)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{253+3 \sqrt[3]{298751-12224 \sqrt{573}}+3
   \sqrt[3]{298751+12224 \sqrt{573}}}}}>11-2\sqrt 2$$ (determined with computer assistance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it should be $$\frac{3}{b}+4\sqrt{b^2+8}\geq11-2\sqrt2,$$ which is true by C-S and AM-GM:
$$\frac{3}{b}+4\sqrt{b^2+8}=\frac{3}{b}+\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{(1+8)(b^2+8)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{3}{b}+\frac{4(b+8)}{3}\geq4+\frac{32}{3}>11-2\sqrt2.$$

Secondly, we can prove your second inequality by the similar way:
$$\frac{3}{b}+2\sqrt{b^2+8}=\frac{3}{b}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{11}}\sqrt{(3+8)(b^2+8)}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{3}{b}+\frac{2(\sqrt3b+8)}{\sqrt{11}}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{6\sqrt3}{\sqrt{11}}}+\frac{16}{\sqrt{11}}>11-2\sqrt2.$$

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the title (now fixed)  But the problem should be solved without the additional factor

Comment: @StackUnderflow I added something. See now.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @StackUnderflow You are welcome!

Comment: A question: Is there any systematic behind the approach you took? For example, why did you split the factor into $(1+8)$ and $(3+8)$ ? More specifically, if we use exactly your approach with a parameter $a$: $$f(b)=\frac3b+\frac2{\sqrt a}\sqrt{((a-8)+8)(b^2+8)},$$ then we can get the best lower bound with your approach for $a\approx 10.9$, see here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NMaximize%5B%7B16%2FSqrt%28a%29%2B2%20Sqrt%286%20Sqrt%28a-8%29%2FSqrt%28a%29%29%2Ca%3E8%7D%2Ca%5D

Comment: @StackUnderflow I took a factor $3+8$ because the equality occurs around $b=\sqrt3.$